# StringFormat on TextBox prevents Input

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, decimal

I need to display and set an exchange rate in a textbox.
My ViewModel contains a `decimal` property named `ExchangeRate`. By default it's only possible to enter up to two decimal places.

Exchange rates usually contains more then two decimal places so I tried to achieve this with StringFormat:

```
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             IsEnabled="{Binding ExchangeRateNeeded}"
             Text="{Binding ExchangeRate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=250, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:0.00000}}"
             Height="23" Margin="130,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" MaxLength="4"/>
```

It displays as wished, but I'm not able to enter a value with this formatting option.

How can I enter more than 2 decimal places?

ViewModel:

```
 public class SetupWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<SapVkorg> SapVkOrgs { get; }
    
    public SapVkorg SelectedVkOrg { get; set; }
    public ICommand OkCommand { get;  }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public bool ApertumNumbers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Currency> Currencies { get; }
    public Currency SelectedCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal ExchangeRate { get; set; }
    public bool ExchangeRateNeeded { get { return SelectedCurrency != Currency.EUR; }  }

    public SetupWindowViewModel(Window window) : base(window)
    {
        OkCommand = new RelayCommand(Save, CanSave);

        SapVkOrgs = mainController.GetSapVkorgs();
        Currencies = mainController.GetCurrencies();

        SelectedVkOrg = SettingsHolder.SapVkorg;
        Year = SettingsHolder.Year;
        ApertumNumbers = SettingsHolder.ApertumNumbers;
        ExchangeRate = SettingsHolder.ExchangeRate;
        SelectedCurrency = SettingsHolder.Currency;
    }


    public void Save()
    {
        SettingsHolder.SapVkorg = SelectedVkOrg;
        SettingsHolder.Year = Year;
        SettingsHolder.Currency = SelectedCurrency;
        SettingsHolder.ExchangeRate = ExchangeRate;
        SettingsHolder.ApertumNumbers = ApertumNumbers;

        CloseWindow();
    }

    public bool CanSave()
    {
        return Year > 0 &&
            SelectedVkOrg != null &&
            ((ExchangeRateNeeded && ExchangeRate != 1) || (!ExchangeRateNeeded));
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase:

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    protected readonly MainController mainController;
    protected static readonly log4net.ILog log = LogHelper.GetLogger();

    protected readonly Window window;

    public ICommand CloseWindowCommand { get; }

    protected ViewModelBase(Window window)
    {
        mainController = MainController.GetInstance();
        this.window = window;

        CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseWindow);

        Initialize();
    }

    protected void CloseWindow()
    {
        window.Close();
    }

    protected bool? ShowDialog(Window windowToOpen)
    {
        windowToOpen.Owner = window;
        return windowToOpen.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        window.DataContext = this;
    }

    protected void DisplayAlertAndLogError(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(message, ex);
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Fehler", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your ViewModel as well?

Comment: `MaxLength="4"` you sure you want that?

Comment: remove MaxLength="4"

Comment: Oh god, copy & paste.... That resolved my issue :(

Comment: Just a little tip, Minimal Examples really do *help*. If you would have stripped down your TextBox to the essential parts `<TextBox Text="{Binding ... }" />`, you would have noticed right away that something other than the binding was at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Freggar in comments: `MaxLength="4"` should be removed